# Передать Google документ в Telegram бота по прямой ссылке

Tags: telegram-bot, google-drive, google-docs, google-docs-api

Подскажите, как передать сгенерированный документ из Google Drive в бота Telegram, через прямую ссылку, чтобы он скачался?

Делал, что-то похожее на с Airtable. Но не очень понимаю как это сделать с Google Docs.
Т.е. там условно брал прямую ссылку на файл, токен бота, user id, давал название документу и все это http запросом отправлял.

`https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendDocument?chat_id=${chat_id}&document=${doc_url}&caption=${caption}`

Comment: документ расшарен?

Comment: будет расшарен. т.е. будет каждый раз передаваться новый документ

Comment: на данный момент какую ошибку Вы получаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы отправить (точнее - экспортировать) Google документ в Телеграм, можно использовать следующий Google скрипт:

```
// Отправка документа в формате PDF в чат Телеграм
function sendDocsAsPDFToTelegram() {
  const BOT_TOKEN = '...';
  const CHAT_ID = '...';
  const FILE_ID = '...';  // идентификатор экспортируемого файла на Google Drive
  var exportUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/' + FILE_ID + '/export?format=pdf';
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() }
  });
  var blob = resp.getBlob().setName('my.pdf');
  var url = 'https://api.telegram.org/' + BOT_TOKEN + 
    '/sendDocument?chat_id=' + CHAT_ID + 
    '&caption=' + encodeURIComponent('Мой документ');
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    payload: { document: blob }
  });
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Вы также можете использовать параметр `format=doc` для экспорта документа в формате DOCX. Аналогично можно экспортировать таблицы Google, используя [разнообразные параметры](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/all-google-docs-url-parameters-functions-commands).